# Exponential Search alternative to std::lower_bound

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, stl

Does the STL include an implementation of exponential search, already?
`std::lower_bound` states complexity logarithmic in the differences between the iterators (begin and end, so often the size of the array), whereas exponential search is logarithmic in the (expected) index of the element to search for.

While it's not hard to implement, I want to avoid an unnecessary re-implementation with it's already tehre and I just cannot find it.

Comment: What's the advantage? The expected index of the element is `N/2`, and `O(log(N/2)) == O(log(N))` If you are working with a special case (where the element is much more likely to be found near the beginning), then it doesn't sound outrageous to have to implement a special-purpose algorithm for a special case.

Comment: You can use exponential search to look for all occurrences of a sorted list of m elements in a list of n elements where n >>> m (and you dont want to iterate through all n elements and compare them). The interface of lower_bound (i.e. using iterators) would already be suited for that

Comment: `The interface of lower_bound would already be suited for that` I don't quite see how. Where would you pass your `m` elements? The interface of `lower_bound` only allows for `m==1`.

Comment: C++ standard library does not contain exponential searches.

Comment: of course, one would have to build around but it would be possible to call lower_bound(list.begin() + nof_elements_done, list.end()) for each subsequent find.
@ÖöTiib : alright, thanks

Comment: Could you give a code example of how this is used?